# Как понять какое нужно ловить исключение python

Tags: python

[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: '' -> ''

Я хочу поймать данное исключение, как узнать название этой ошибки, чтобы в дальнейшем поймать её с помощью try exept?

Comment: Каким кодом вызвана эта ошибка? Это не исключение питона.

Comment: Название класса ищите в сообщении об ошибке прямо перед WinError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае лучше проверить существование файла методом, а не блоком try.

```py
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path(file_name)
if path.exists():
    # логика, если файл существует
else:
    # создание файла
```

Если решите оставить try, то попробуйте `except IOError`, либо в общем случае для улавливания всех возможных исключений напишите `except BaseException`.

Comment: Если путь существует, это не значит: 1) что файл можно открыть и прочитать, 2) что это вообще файл, а не папка 3) что он все еще будет существовать к моменту начала работы с ним 4) что это будет тот же файл, что при проверке. Отлавливать исключения в python предпочтительнее (EAFP), но отлавливать базовое - почти всегда плохая идея.